# How can I do a Django Query on a JSONField containing a date?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

my hope was I could do something like this:

```
Q(data__result_started__gt = dateutil.parser.parse("5/22/18"))
```

or

```
Q(data__result_started__gt = "2018-5-22")
```

in the first case i get a datetime is not JSON serializable error and in the second case i get 0 results returned.

Is there a way to do this?
thanks

Comment: To start with: **you're comparing texts.** There is no date type in json. If [this (note: postgres specific)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield) does not work, I can suggest creating a view in postgres that provides the id and the date it extracts from json (or jsonb).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `__gt` postfix to filter on json sub fields. This is not supported yet in the django ORM. It is possible to do this with raw sql in postgresql, so maybe this feature will be added in a future release of Django.

If you provide your model code, someone might suggest an answer using sql.

You can also extract the sub field using `.annotate()` and then use that in subsequent django QuerySet queries. See this question for an example.

[Ordering Django querysets using a JSONField's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693812/ordering-django-querysets-using-a-jsonfields-properties)

Comment: are you sure about the __gt postfix? I am doing things like data__build_version__gt=1.5 and that seems to work

Comment: If that's possible, some implementation might already be in place in recent django versions, but not yet documented. So I suspect it's a partial implementation, which explains why the date comparison doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the django json encoder date format: `Q(data__result_started__gt = "2018-05-22T00:00:00")`. Or only date, but use zero padding for date and month.

Answer (score 0):

I found using `strftime` useful as we can tailor how we require the final format. In `JSONField` datetime is usually presented as `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ`. So you can try,

```
json_field_datetime = python_datetime_field.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```